# Scala script highlighting in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I've got a rather large project set up in intellij. The project uses scala scripts to specify various instances of the program.

It used to be the case that the scala scripts were in a resources directory of the project, but, this is not ideal. I've moved them, so my project looks like this (the idea is, ultimately, to move them away completely)

```
+Project root
  +subproject
    +src.main.resources
        [Scripts were here]
     pom
     iml
   pom
   iml

  +scripts
      [scripts are now here]
```

but now intellij syntax highlighting does not recognise the scripted imports relating to the project. Is there some way of getting intellij to recognise the dependency of these scripts without going back to a module structure and the src/main/resources folder?

Comment: First of all... Please don't call them `scripts`. You should call them `source code files`.

Comment: And since it is a `maven` project, you must follow the `maven project structure` which says that all the source code should be inside `src` folder.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh They're scripts, i.e. they're interpreted at runtime using a repl built into the main project!

Comment: So, since they're actually scripts, I can put them where I like

Answer (score 1):

Define `scripts` as a source folder:

`File > Project Structure > Modules > Sources`

and mark `scripts` as `Sources` (blue icon).

You can find more info on [IntelliJ WebHelp](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/content-root.html).

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve it, but it is very useful to know! I've ended up just giving the folder a pom and that seems to work, though its not that elegant a solution.